# C split string into string array using strtok() without NULL as last element

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, split, strtok

I have a string like this:

```
"monday,wednesday,friday"
```

And I'd like to save this into an array of char arrays (~array of strings).

```
char **splitString(char *string, int size, char delimiter)
{
  char **ptr = (char **)malloc(size * sizeof(char *));
  int i = 0;
  ptr[i] = strtok(string, &delimiter);
  while (ptr[i] != NULL)
  {
    ptr[++i] = strtok(NULL, &delimiter);
  }
  return ptr;
}
```

Managed to do it with the code above, but since it always checks the current tokenized string it does not stop with the last one and reads an additional `NULL`. Printing out the array I get:

```
The 0. element is: monday
The 1. element is: wednesday
The 2. element is: friday
The 3. element is: (null)
```

Is there a concise and simple way to know when the loop is reaching the last element?

Comment: It is unclear where does size appear from. Secondly how will you  determine how many actual elements  were extracted?

Comment: In essence it is a very good approach that the last pointer is equal to NULL. It is you who incorrectly uses the array. That is all.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Why am I using incorrectly the array? I asked how  can I remove it, not the go into philosophical discussion whether it is needed or not. This is why most of the C stackoverflow examples are useless, because all the answers are focusing on 70% logic which has nothing to do with the question. Also why should it be important where the size appear from. It also has nothing to do with the question. If I don't know it already then it is going to fill the function with a lot of logic, sure. But that has nothing to do with the main question again.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Ok, now that is a bit more specific. I may use a bad approach for sure. But if there are already know good approaches, why am I have to write it? Why is the good approach not already in the standard? Surely someone with more proper perspectives have written a lot of general functions like this for C already, following the good approaches. I think pointing out my bad approach is not useful at the moment. This makes again, all the C examples I see almost useless, because even the simplest abstract logic becomes a 3x that size code with allocations and reallocations everywhere.

Comment: I asked about the parameter size because in your question you wrote that  "The 3. element is: (null)" Now when this element marked by you as 3 is not initialized what will be outputted instead of null? An indeterminate value?

Comment: Then where is this line "The 3. element is: (null)" from? In fact nothing was changed.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Oooooouch. I think I understand what you mean now and what I might not fully understand. I'm printing out the array using the same `size` parameter there.

Comment: Then nothing was changed. Now instead of the value null in this element you will have indeterminate value. That is all.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow /*facepalm*/ Yes I see your point now. Sorry for being impatient. I'm having a hard time to create proper C code with my pythonic mindset. Even the tiniest function takes hours for me at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this

```
char **splitString(char *string, int size, char delimiter)
{
  char **ptr = (char **)malloc(size * sizeof(char *));
  char *p;
  int i = 0;
  p = strtok(string, &delimiter);
  while (p != NULL)
  {
    ptr[i++] = p;
    p = strtok(NULL, &delimiter);
  }
  return ptr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great idea Marc, I haven't thought about using a helper pointer, my own solution had blindfolded me. Could you clarify the logic and the important difference of the incrementation order so the whole answer could be more explicit? Thanks again :)

Comment: @MattSom This is just a bad approach. How will you determine how many elements in the filled array?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I know what you mean, but in this example I don't. I know some checks should be on the size of the string array or on the input string but it is implicitly checked elsewhere. I did not want to focus on that logic at the moment.

Comment: I did not say the approach at large is sane, I just wanted to eliminate the NULL in the last position.  I used postincrement so that we start with 0.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can accomplish your goal, just by changing each `,` to `\0` and setting an array of pointers to the first character of the string, and to each character after a `,`. Somehow like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char **split_string(char *str, int *size) {
    int i;
    *size = 1;
    printf("size = %d\n", *size);
    char **array = malloc(*size * sizeof(char *));
    array[0] = &str[0];
    for (i = 1; str[i] != 0; i++) {
        if (str[i] == ',') {
            (*size)++;
            printf("size = %d\n", *size);
            array = realloc(array, sizeof(char *) * (*size));
            array[(*size) - 1] = &str[i + 1];
            str[i] = '\0';
        }
    }
    return array;
}

int main() {
    char str[] = "one,two,three";
    int size;
    char **array = split_string(str, &size);
    for (int i=0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This grows the array dynamically, which is quite nice, also omits using `strtok`. I did not want to focus on that, because it brings in a lot of implicit logic, but I like this anyway. Thanks for the contribution! :)

Comment: Just providing a different approach on the problem. My pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use , as a separator with simple loop :

```
counter = 0;
counter2;
char thing [][]
char YourString 
for(i = 0;i<=20;i++){

if(YourString !=","){
thing[counter][i]=yourString[counter2]
}
else{
counter++;
}
counter2++;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry Sefa, but this is not reflecting to the code I've subtmitted, also has errors.

Comment: It's Pseudo code and the strings separate by , like first string on [1][thing] second string on [2][thing] the first counter stores string

Comment: This is absolutely not a pseudo code Sefa, this is a not formatted C code with hard coded size value and static array. Please format it first and if you want to write pseudo code then go for true pseudo code, not a half made actual code. You use semicolons at some parts and omit them at other parts, that is not the definition of pseudocoding.

Comment: As long as it's representing the algorithm